# Different spacing between horizontal and vertical list item

Tags: html, css

The space between horizontal and vertical list item appears differently, even through the margin, padding, height and width are exactly the same for both layouts. I would like them to be the same, I know I can manually adjust the margins or paddings, but why are they not the same, is there a simple way to keep them consistent? thanks.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="horizontal">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<ul class="vertical">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background: #333333;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.horizontal li {
    float: left;
}
```

see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/3ZbkQ/

Comment: I'm guessing the is something to do with margin collapse. If you remove the margin you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/3ZbkQ/1/

Comment: Like mentioned in the comments above it has to do with collapsing margins. Read more about margins (and collapsing) on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/)

Comment: btw, when you apply the `float:left` style to the horizontal list, that means the 2 lists are different, not the same as you described. That's why your problem occurred. A list is float element while the other is inline element and float elements don't be effected by margin-collapsing rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical `li`'s margin are [collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). You can get around this with:

```
.vertical li {
    float: left; /*a floated box's margin does not collapse with any other box */
    clear: left; /* Push each succeeding li to a new line, 
                    though not needed on the first */
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZbkQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins
Your vertical margin is collapsing, cause your elements are 'next' to each other.
In difference to that, horizontal margins are not collapsing.